# VirtualBox virtual machine is suddenly not accessible

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu on VirtualBox and Windows host machine. Suddenly I am getting flow error. Any idea to fix this issue? I do not want to install Ubuntu again as will loose lot of data.

[image]

Comment: You have a missing file.  Point VirtualBox to the correct file or move the file you want to use to the correct location.

Comment: In this path. I am seeing two files. ubuntu.vbox-pre and ubuntu.vox-tmp and not able to see ubuntu.vox file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that VirtualBox can’t find the file in that path for the VirtualBox machine. What I do in cases like this is *delete the machine but do not delete the files* so the machine is removed from the VirtualBox list but the files connected to it are left untouched. Then find the actual virtual machine files, double-click the `ubuntu.vbox` file to get it reimported and there you go! It should work.

If somehow there is no `ubuntu.vbox` file, but there *is* a backup named `ubuntu.vbox-prev` or `ubuntu.vbox-pre` then quit VirtualBox, copy that file and rename it so it becomes `ubuntu.vbox` with the `.vbox` extension.

When that is done, restart VirtualBox and it should now be able to find file and all should be good.

Answer (score 2):

Something must have gone corrupted. A definite solution to recover from such situations is simply to make a copy of the Ubuntu's virtual hard drive (`.vdi` file) and than create another virtual machine and set it to use the `.vdi` copy you've created. Provided it worked, you can just get rid of the files of the VM not working.

#### Find the .vdi

Since you've commented you can't find anything other than `ubuntu.vbox-pre` and `ubuntu.vox-tmp` in the VM's folder, is it possible you placed the disk in a different directory when creating the VM? Try going to `file menu` on Virtualbox  and choosing  `Virtual Media Manager`. See whether you can find the virtual disk path there.

#### Clone the disk

Just making a plain copy of the disk won't work, VirtualBox will accuse it detected duplicated disks. So, you've got to clone the disk:

1. Run the command prompt by pressing `windows button + r` and typing `cmd`
2. Enter Virtualbox installation directory. i.e.: `cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` (the partition might differ, in my case, it's C:. Also, you might have a 86x version of Virtualbox in which case you should enter `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\VirtualBox`)
3. Run `VBoxManage clonehd <old> <new> --format VDI` replacing `<old>` by the current ubuntu hard drive and `<new>` for the new hard drive that will be created.

#### Create the new VM with the new virtual disk file

Once you've created a copy, just create a new virtual machine, and at the time you're prompt to choose an existing virtual disk file, just point it to the disk you've cloned.

Comment: Could been my answer :P

Answer (score 0):

The inaccessibility means VM can not read the VM file PATH for it to function or run, for some unknown reason an extension is added to the file itself. On your physical machine go to the File PATH as stated with "Runtime error openning" C:\ users....... and remove any what or ever the extra extension on ubuntu.vbox and save it as ubuntu.vbox
Start your machine and you are good to go!

Comment: I'm not perfectly clear what you’re saying.  (Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.)   If you’re saying what I believe you’re saying, you are duplicating the accepted answer.